# Uservoice and stackoverflow sharing common javascript library for flash messages?

Tags: javascript, html

I was using UserVoice and noted that flash messages are like StackOverflow.

Is there any common library to build something like this?

```
  <div class="uservoice-component">
      <div id="flashes" class="has-layout">
    <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
setTimeout("$$('.message').each(function(element){ new Effect.Appear(element); });", 0);
//]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
setTimeout("$$('.temporary-message').each(function(element){ new Effect.Fade(element); });", 7000);
//]]>
</script>
    <noscript>
      <p class="error">Please enable Javascript <small>(it's required)</small></p>
    </noscript>
  </div>
```

Thanks!
Pablo

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you're asking for. The example code you gave looks like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to me, which is a relatively standard library.

Answer (score 0):

It's just using JQuery to cause an alert to pop up, pretty standard JQuery if you ask me. Just make a div with the message you want, and call something like `$('#someid').show();`

Alex